# The app doesn't work

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I'm working on my CourtCounter app, but I have 3 bugs
1) when you are trying to add a point for Peat,it doesn't work. All points are going for Marta's account
2) When I'm pushing Reset button, the whole app is restarting (just it is stopping). I think it should just restart the result
3) The image at the background - as you can see, it's expanted. It doesn't look good. I think I just have to use pic with proper size, dedicated for the phone?
*[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfTF6.png)*

****Code**

**activity_main****

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/a"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip">




    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">



        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context="com.example.majka.courtcounter.MainActivity">



            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text="MARTA'S TEAM"
                android:textColor="#FF040510"
                android:background="#c2c2c6"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:elevation="2dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/martas_team_score"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="80sp"
                android:paddingBottom="24dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>


            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:onClick="addThreeToTeamA"
                android:text="+3 points"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="#3F51B5"
                android:textColor="#ECEFF1"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:onClick="addTwoToTeamA"
                android:text="+2 points"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="#3F51B5"
                android:textColor="#ECEFF1"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:onClick="addOneToTeamA"
                android:text="Free Throw"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="#3F51B5"
                android:textColor="#ECEFF1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context="com.example.majka.courtcounter.MainActivity">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text=" PEAT'S TEAM"
                android:textColor="#040510"
                android:background="#c2c2c6"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:elevation="2dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_2_scores"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="80sp"
                android:paddingBottom="24dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>


            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:onClick="addThreeToTeamA"
                android:text="+3 points"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="#673AB7"
                android:textColor="#ECEFF1"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:onClick="addTwoToTeamA"
                android:text="+2 points"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="#673AB7"
                android:textColor="#ECEFF1"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:onClick="addOneToTeamA"
                android:text="Free Throw"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="#673AB7"
                android:textColor="#ECEFF1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

     <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RESET"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="ResetScore"
        android:background="#B0BEC5"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**mainActivity**

```
package com.example.majka.courtcounter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int scoreTeamA = 0;
    int scoreTeamB = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        displayForTeamA(0);
    }

    public void addThreeToTeamA (View v ) {
        scoreTeamA = scoreTeamA + 3;
        displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);

    }

    public void addTwoToTeamA (View v ) {
        scoreTeamA = scoreTeamA + 2;
        displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);

    }

    public void addOneToTeamA (View v ) {
        scoreTeamA = scoreTeamA + 1;
        displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);

    }

    public void addOneForTeamB(View v) {
        scoreTeamB = scoreTeamB + 1;
        displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);
    }

    /**
     * Increase the score for Team B by 2 points.
     */
    public void addTwoForTeamB(View v) {
        scoreTeamB = scoreTeamB + 2;
        displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);
    }

    /**
     * Increase the score for Team B by 3 points.
     */
    public void addThreeForTeamB(View v) {
        scoreTeamB = scoreTeamB + 3;
        displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);
    }


    /**
     * Displays the given score for Team A.
     */
    public void displayForTeamA(int score) {
        TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.martas_team_score);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }

    /**
     * Displays the given score for Team B.
     */
    public void displayForTeamB(int score) {
        TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.peats_team_score);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }

    public void resetScore(View v) {
        scoreTeamA = 0;
        scoreTeamB = 0;
        displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
        displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me?
I don't see the mistake into code. I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, post question updates like edits to your original question, and not as answers, as they are not answers. I have flagged them for that reason. Also, it is always better to provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than all your code, as it is easier for the community to check on that. So please edit your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) In your buttons for Peat's team, the `onClick` attributes are using Team A's methods.

2) Your reset button's `onClick` attribute is referencing a method named `ResetScore`, but the method you have defined in your code is named `resetScore` (note the lowercase "r"). This is causing your app to crash.

3) You may wish to use a different image or, if you switch to using the `android:src` attribute, you can control the scaling of your image using the [`android:scaleType`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) attribute.

Comment: hi. Thank you for your tips. I used all of them, but now the app doesn't work too :(

Comment: @MartaOniszk When you run the app from Android Studio, what error messages are you getting in the Logcat window?

Comment: it works. I checked logcat window. I checked the whole code again and it works. :-)